# How to call a function whenever global variable changes it value?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I call a function `change_label` whenever global variable `a` changes its value?  With `change_variable` I am trying to simulate actual changing of the variable (the variable changes on button click).

```
from tkinter import *

a = 3

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Change Variable', command=self.change_variable)
        self.button.grid(row=0)
        self.label = Label(self.master, text='Test')
        self.label.grid(row=1)

    def change_label(self):
        self.label.config(bg='Red', fg='Yellow')

    def change_variable(self):
        global a
        a = 1

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If it isn't an issue, you can use a lightweight thread to monitor the value periodically.

Comment: okay, why don't you just call `change_label` in all places that change `a`?

Comment: Also, check this out: [How to trigger function on value change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190468/how-to-trigger-function-on-value-change)

Comment: Why not use a property on an object instead of a global then you could call your function from the setter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use one of tkinters special variables (`StringVar`, etc) you can add a "trace" that will trigger a callback whenever the variable is set or unset.

For example:

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ...
        self.a = tk.IntVar(value=3)
        self.a.trace("w", self.change_label)
        ...

    def change_label(self, *args):
        self.label.config(bg='Red', fg='Yellow')

    def change_variable(self):
        self.a.set(1)
```

With that, whenever you set the value of `self.a` via the `set` method, the function bound with the `trace` will be called.

Any widget that uses that variable also will be updated. For example, change your label to this:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self.master, textvariable=self.a)
```

When you click the button, notice that the label changes to reflect the change.

For a description of what arguments are passed to the trace function, see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432)

These variables have a good description here: [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Tk`, this might be worth looking into: [`Tk`'s "Variable" classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

If that doesn't work for you (because you want to store your own type, or something like that), `Shiva`'s comment is the way to go, and if you want to store multiple variables, this might be a good idea:

```
class Storage(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return self[name]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print(name, value)  # react to the change of name
        self[name] = value

storage = Storage({a: 3, b: 2})

storage.a = 4
print(storage.a)
```

If you don't want to be able to set the variable without triggering some code you put there, good luck. You can override `__setitem__` too, but you can always call `dict.__setitem__` with the `Storage` variable as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code it will give you the idea of what you want.

```
import tkinter
count = 5
def change_text():
        global count
        if count != 2:
                button.config(text='edit')

frame = tkinter.Frame(height=500,width=500)
button = tkinter.Button(frame,text='save',command=change_text)
button.place(x=0,y=0)
frame.pack()
frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
The code was supposed be like this.
from tkinter import *

a = 3

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Change Variable', command=self.change_label)
        self.button.grid(row=0)
        self.label = Label(self.master, text='Test')
        self.label.grid(row=1)

    def change_label(self):
        global a
        a = 1
        if a != 3:
            self.label.config(bg='Red', fg='Yellow')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
hope that is what you wanted.
```

Comment: Why did you add a second answer? What does "the code was supposed to be like this" mean? Are you aware you can edit your original answer?

Comment: you don't need the change_variable method you can still do all that in one method the change_variable method like have done.