# I cant update labels in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I can't seem to update my money counter(var money) when its labeled, I have a button that's supposed to add 0.1 to moneyNum but the money counter doesn't change. I'm new to stack overflow and would appreciate any help.(btw sry if its REALLY messy)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
root.geometry('320x320')

#spacing
spacingTitle = Label(root, text=" \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")



#title
title = Label(root, text="                        \bGamblers Dream\b", font="Helvetica", fg="red")
titleWelcom = Label(root, text="                        Welcom to...")
titleWelcom.grid()
title.grid()


#money counter
moneyNum = float(10.0)
money = Label(root, text="money:" + str(moneyNum), font="Helvetica")
money.grid(row=3, column=0)

#moneyClicker
def moneyButtonAdder():
    global moneyNum
    moneyNum = moneyNum + 0.1
moneyClicker = Button(root, text="click", fg="green", command=moneyButtonAdder)
moneyClicker.grid(row=14)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005)

Comment: Just update `moneyNum` will not update `money` label.  Add `money.config(text="money:"+str(moneyNum))` after updating `moneyNum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you create a label, you pass the string to it. Label displays the string, and:

1. changing a string object does not change the label text
2. changing the integer does not change the string - it lost the whole connection when the new string object was created
   So everything is not as procedural as you would have hoped it is.
   The solution - use `StringVar` objects and detect value changes - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190468/how-to-trigger-function-on-value-change).
   So, the solution is:

```
from tkinter import *

class Observed(object):
    """adapted copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192298/10713244"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._observed = 10.0
        self._observers = []

    @property
    def observed(self):
        return self._observed

    @observed.setter
    def observed(self, value):
        self._observed = value
        for callback in self._observers:
            print('announcing change')
            callback(self._observed)

    def bind_to(self, callback):
        print('bound')
        self._observers.append(callback)


class Observer(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.text = ''
        self.data = data
        self.data.bind_to(self.update)

        self.tkinter_init()
    def update(self, observed):
        self.text = 'float: '+str(data._observed)

        self.tkinter_update()

    def tkinter_init(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tvar = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(textvariable=self.tvar)
        self.label.pack()
    def tkinter_update(self):
        self.tvar.set(self.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Observed()
    label = Observer(data)
    print(label.text)
    data.observed = 10.0
    print(label.text)

    def dec(): data.observed -= 0.1
    Button(label.tk, text='decrease', command=dec).pack()

    label.tk.mainloop()
```

Hope that's helpful!