# Writing all the values to a text file in Python

Tags: python, csv

The quantity `A` is constantly updated. I want to write all the values of `A` to a `.txt` file and not just the last value. `A=120,100,10` where `120` is the value in the first iteration and `10` is the value in the last iteration.

```
with open('Data_A.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f) 
    A=10
    print(A)
    f.writelines('A'+ '\n')
    f.write(str(A))
```

The current output is

```
A
10
```

The expected output is

```
A
120
100
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues in your attempt**: You need to append to the file rather than overwriting it each time i.e. use the `'a'` instead of `'w'` mode.

**Solution - Invoke function**: Here is a sample solution demonstrating how to append to a file by invoking a function:

```
def create():
    with open('Data_A.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('A\n')


def update(value):
    with open('Data_A.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{value}\n')
    return value


# example
create()
a = update(120)
a = update(100)
a = update(10)
```

The code is in a function that you can call each time you change the value.

We can open the file outside of the `update` function but this would mean that the file remains open until released e.g. the program is closed. Opening the file in the `update` function releases the file straightaway after the appending is complete but would be slower if you are making a lot of calls repeatedly.

Similarly, we can access the global variable directly in the `update` function but this is [generally discouraged](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/global-variables). Instead, we return the value.

**Alternative solutions**: You can use [object-oriented approach with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190468/how-to-trigger-function-on-value-change).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should open your file in append mode. Use `a` instead of `w` when you open the file.

Secondly, if your code changes the value of `A`, and whenever it changes, you want it to be printed to the file, use a function you can call instead of directly changing the value of `A`. This function should write the new value to the file and update the variable's value.

```py
def update_value_of_a(new_value):
    A = new_value
    f.write(str(A) + '\n')
```

Then, instead of writing something like `A = 120` use `update_value_of_a(120)`.

Make sure you define the function in a scope that can access the `f` variable.